# mysqldump unknown database bitnami_redmine

Tags: database, mysql, redmine, bitnami

I'm currently trying to migrate the mysql database from the Bitnami Redmine stack on a Windows machine to Ubuntu.

When I try to mysqldump the database following happens:

> C:\BitNami\redmine-2.3.1-1\mysql\bin>mysqldump -u root -p bitnami_redmine > backup_redmine.sql
>   Enter password: ************
>   mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'bitnami_redmine' when selecting the database

mysqlshow give following output:

```
C:\BitNami\redmine-2.3.1-1\mysql\bin>mysqlshow -u root -p
Enter password: ************
+--------------------+
|     Databases      |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mantis             |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

Can someone tell me why bitnami_redmine database isn't shown under mysql databases?

Thanks a lot,

moatze

Comment: Because your database is not setup on this server ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database really exists on that server, the root user does not have permissions to see it, but that is not very likely unless you have specifically limited the permissions of the root user.
Otherwise, like Kevin mentioned in the comment, the database does not exist on that server.

Answer (score 0):

This happend to **because of WAMP**.

My setup was:

- MySQL server installed by me (not provided by WAMP)
- WAMP installed afterwards

**When WAMP was started**:

- command line mysql commands for root@localhost would **not show most of my databases**
- WAMP PHP MYADMIN would show all my databases when connecting to root@localhost

**When WAMP was stopped**:

- command line mysql commands for root@localhost would **show all of my "missing" databases**